# Query many-to-many related data using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two entities that have a many-to-many relationship. I also have an entity between then that holds the two ID's. I want to load only the two main entities.

My entities:

```
public class User 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role 
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole 
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public long RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Expected JSON result:

```
{
  "Email": ...
  "Roles": [
    {"Name": ...},
    {"Name": ...},
    ...
  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EF Core doesn't technically support M2M relationships. You can fake said support via a "join" entity, which connects the two sides of the relationship, as you have here with `UserRole`. There's no way around this, unfortunately, so if you don't want to see the `UserRole` relationship in your results, you'll have to manually reshape the data. For example:

```
var users = await _context.Users.Select(u => new
{
    Email = u.Email,
    Roles = u.UserRoles.Select(r => r.Role)
}).ToListAsync();
```

*Pro Tip: You don't need `Include` if you're selecting from relationships. EF Core is smart enough to issue joins in order to fill the data.*

Comment: You typically don't, since it's just a relationship. If the relationship no longer exists, you delete it. If there's a new relationship, you add it.